# (VBA) Reading txt file as FileSystemObject through TextStream throws error

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I am writing a makro to read thousands of big text files, analyse their content and save a desired part of its content into my Excel worksheet.
On another thread it said that the readAll method of a TextStream object is a good way to do so, so I copied a piece of code and built my makro around it.
Every few hundred textfiles though it throws a weird error. The file being processed is being emptied by my makro and the makro stops working. 
Again: Before I start the makro the textfile that throws an error has content in it(as far as I can see it looks like any other textfile), but when Excel throws the error the textfile's content is deleted.

Can you think of the reason for this error or suggest an alternative that might now give this error?

```
Function readFileContent(FILENAME As String) As String
'reads the txt file into a string and deletes parts before the first "<TestFlow" Element`
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim lngLength As Long

Dim fsoMyFile As FileSystemObject
Dim tsTempo As TextStream
Dim StrContent As String

lngStart = 0
lngLength = 0

Set fsoMyFile = New FileSystemObject
Set tsTempo = fsoMyFile.OpenTextFile(FILENAME, ForReading)
StrContent = tsTempo.ReadAll

Set tsTempo = fsoMyFile.OpenTextFile(FILENAME, ForWriting, False, TristateFalse)
tsTempo.Write (StrContent)

'Cut of everything up to the first <TextFlow tag

lngStart = InStr(StrContent, "<TextFlow")
        If lngStart = 0 Then
        readFileContent = "SKIPPED"
        End If
lngLength = Len(StrContent)
StrContent = Right(StrContent, lngLength - lngStart)
readFileContent = StrContent

End Function
```

The line StrContent = tsTempo.ReadAll is the line where the program stops. I get no error message.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing... You use **same** variable and **same** file name for reading and writing?

Comment: OK, may be this is so, but before opening text file second time for *writing*, you should close it: `tsTempo.Close`. And also should close after writing.

Comment: wow thank you very much. Closing the document again has helped

Comment: As I can guess, you call this function in a loop. This is not efficient 'cause for 1000 files you instantiate 1000 instances of FileSystemObject. You should create FSO once and reuse during the loop time. The same goes for TextStream.

Comment: actually I have tenths of thousands of documents, so I should definitively pursue an efficient approach.
So, if I understood correctly you suggest me to:
Declare the FSO and the TextStream once in my mother sub, then pass them over to my function where I assign different files to them with every call?
I have never tried to pass them over, so I will experiment with this solution but I get why instantiating thousands of objects is a inefficient thing to do :-)
Thank you very much for you input! I am new here and am happy about every hint I can get.

Comment: Here's one [example](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCjn8se8XWQ0qBhDpv) of how you can speed up your work a bit. :) As you can see, only one instance of FSO is at work. Try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use same file name for reading and writing, you should close it after each operation:

```
Set fsoMyFile = New FileSystemObject
Set tsTempo = fsoMyFile.OpenTextFile(FILENAME, ForReading)
StrContent = tsTempo.ReadAll
tsTempo.Close '// <=== CLOSE

Set tsTempo = fsoMyFile.OpenTextFile(FILENAME, ForWriting, False, TristateFalse)
tsTempo.Write (StrContent)
tsTempo.Close '// <=== CLOSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, closing the document between operations has helped!